# Extrcat Value From Grib2 weather file C#?

Tags: c#, grib

I'm working on weather data visualization and to get data I'm using Grib2 files which has all weather information regarding weather, and their parameters based values. I'm able to get Grib2 files but I'm stuck to get data from the files using C#. Has someone done similar things? I'm looking for any C# library that could help me to extract weather parameter values with Lat/Lon (e.g wind, temperature, cloud etc) from grib2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done the similar work for mobile app and doing exact you are looking for, you can use [GribCS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gribcs) library or [GribApi.Net](https://github.com/0x1mason/GribApi.NET)

It will help you to get start on this.

Cheers!!